# Can't change Content Type header of fileDownload.js jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, download

I am using the jQuery plugin called [fileDownload.js](https://github.com/johnculviner/jquery.fileDownload)

I cannot seem to change the `Content-Type` header to anything at all.
The default is `x-www-form-urlencoded`.

On my express server that is the only header I have been able to get from fileDownload.js

Here is what my code looks like.

```
$.fileDownload(url, {
    httpMethod:'POST',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    data: inputData,
    dataType: 'json',
    successCallback: function() {},
    failCallback: function() {}
});
```

Any ideas why I can't get any content type besides the default `x-www-form-urlencoded`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer by looking at the source. Using this plugin you cannot change the header. Instead I parsed the data I wanted and put it into the url.